# Add parallax effect to buttons in Android

Tags: android

Is it possible to add parallax effect to buttons in my layout? I did a search and I found ParallexScrollView and all.. But how can I achieve it on buttons in a layout?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you state it clear, Scrollview can be parallelaxed since its huge and the effect is based on its background. How do you think about the effect in a button

Comment: Parallax effect on *Buttons*? You have to elaborate on that one.

Comment: I have seen webpages where text, images and all are floating when we scroll..Please check this link http://boy-coy.com/#apps I thought this might be possible in Android for buttons also…But I m not sure on this…Thats why I asked...

Comment: @Mathew, how did you achieved this parallax effect on button? I am planning to achieve the same on images. I want the image to look like floating above the background.